# Deleting multiple files in a zip using Java FileSystems

Tags: java, filesystems, zip

```
public static void deleteFilesInZip(
    String zipStringPath,
    List<String> paths
) throws IOException
{
    Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<>();
    env.put("create", "false");
    Path zipPath = Paths.get(zipStringPath);
    URI uri = URI.create("jar:" + zipPath.toUri());
    try (FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env))
    {
        for(String path: paths)
        {
            Path filePath = fs.getPath(path);
            Files.delete(filePath);
        }
    }
}
```

The above logic works fine in MAC OS but is throwing following error in Windows:

ERROR: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Users\XSXDXX\Downloads\Test.zip: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

What is the best way to delete files in a Zip when I know the paths of the files I need to delete beforehand ?

Comment: Which line causes the exception?  Is it the `FileSystems.newFileSystem` line?  Are you sure the .zip file isn’t open?  Did whatever code write the .zip file remember to close its OutputStream?

Answer (score 0):

You should keep in mind that the path slashes in windows are reversed: c:\
Can you give an example of your path?

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.  And Windows generally accepts forward slashes as file separators, and even if it didn’t, the exception doesn’t seem to be related to that.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue.
Nothing wrong with the above code, turns out there is a Zip Reader service being used which doesn't close the zip Entry. Wonder why this didn't cause an issue in MAC OS.